# Disk failure, fsck not doing anything

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, fsck

**Note: This started off as a question but while i was typing i tried different things and eventually got it working. I still wanted to post it in case it can help anyone else**

Problem: Crashed disk, cant be mounted.
My guess is that bad usb in my pc or the cable caused this crash.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Disk: external raid 5 array "4 bay soho raid", about 3 months old
Partition: sde1, ext4, 8.2TB
Disk manager shows disk and partition, including type and other info. SMART data shows "Self-tests: Completed OK" and "Overall Assessment: Disk is Healthy".

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=9540030a-323d-483f-8fdc-20dbaa09bcaf /mnt/Data    ext4    defaults,async,errors=remount-ro  0  0
```

**mount -a**

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so
```

**lsblk**

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sde      8:64   0   8.2T  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   0   8.2T  0 part
```

**fdisk /dev/sde -l**

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sde: 9001.6 GB, 9001613918208 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1094383 cylinders, total 17581277184 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

**sfdisk -l /dev/sde**

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util sfdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sde: 1094383 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1          0+ 267349- 267350- 2147483647+  ee  GPT
        start: (c,h,s) expected (0,0,2) found (0,0,1)
/dev/sde2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sde3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sde4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
```

**dmesg | tail**

```
[ 9605.609668] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328274
[ 9605.609671] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328275
[ 9605.609673] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328276
[ 9605.609676] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328277
[ 9605.609678] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328278
[ 9605.609681] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328279
[ 9605.670459] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328152
[ 9605.670466] Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 17578328153
[ 9806.549854] EXT4-fs (sde1): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum for group 0 failed (59348!=46035)
[ 9806.549859] EXT4-fs (sde1): group descriptors corrupted!
```

**parted /dev/sde**

```
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sde

Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit TB                                                          
(parted) print                                                            

Model: HzW RAID 5 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 9.00TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      0.00TB  9.00TB  9.00TB  ext4
```

**fsck -CfDy /dev/sde1**
*Note: I ran this a total of 4 times, it seemed like the errors were repeating and fsck wasnt actually doing anything but there were slight differences between each run. Also in duration, the first 2 took hours, the last 2 an hour or less.

This is the description of the last run it made:

Lots of this: (in all 4 runs)

```
Group descriptor xxxxx checksum is invalid.  FIXED.
```

then about an hour of this (first 2 runs many hours, last 2 about an hour)

```
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
```

then these 2 in a few seconds

```
Pass 2: Checking directory structure                                           
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
```

a few minutes on

```
Pass 3A: Optimising directories
```

with a a bunch of these around the 98% mark

```
free blocks count wrong for group #59104 (28640, counted=28617).
Fix? yes
```

in the earlier runs i got very different error messages here, it was asking if i wanted to ignore an issue, if i entered "no" then fsck just quite. if i entered yes then i got another question to which i answered yes. I got thousands of these so i just put a weight on my [enter] key and left it to it (took quite a while).

after the last run i got

```
Data: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
Data: 716082/274710528 files (2.4% non-contiguous), 1193918074/2197659639 blocks
```

** sudo mount -a**
the disk was mounted but no directories or files were visible. It did say "available space" 3.8gb which would be about correct but I couldnt see the files that should have been there taking up the rest of the space. It wass Dark Data! (it's there and can be observed by the space it takes up, but you cant see it directly).

** sudo umount /mnt/Data**

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sde: 9001.6 GB, 9001613918208 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1094383 cylinders, total 17581277184 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

** sudo mount -a**
ah! finally :D the disk is mounted and i can see directories again. No idea why it worked this time but im not complaining!
I see 2 lost+found directories, one with a prefixed ".". But both seem empty.
I decided to run a compare against my backup.

**rsync -rvnc --delete [mountedDir] [backupDir]**

and, to be sure, i also ran
**sudo diff -qr [mountedDir] [backupDir]**

Took a while to run these but it seems everything is as it should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rule 1. dont panic
rule 2. stay positive

keep running fsck and keep an eye on it for any differences indicating that some progress is being made!

Disclaimer, this worked for me but no promises it will work for you. each situation is different. the different commands i ran can give you an indication if your disk issues are similar.